# Skip requests from HTTP Interceptors for login request

Tags: http, httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I have an angular application which intercepts all outgoing requests with HTTP Interceptor to add authentication token to the request.
I dont want this for the login request. So that i have been using http module for this. How can I use httpClientModule for this purpose without intercepting with the HTTP Interceptor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use HttpBackend which will dispatch the request via browser HTTP APIs directly to the backend, without going through the interceptor chain.

```
import { HttpBackend, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, handler: HttpBackend) {
    this.httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
  }
```

Then, use this instance of httpClient for REST.

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular 12 you can use [`HttpContext`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpContext) to handle this case. Each request can provide a context object, that is available in the interceptors to alter their behaviour.

=================

1. Create a `HttpContextToken`

```js
import { HttpContextToken } from '@angular/common/http';

export const DISABLE_AUTH_HEADER =
    new HttpContextToken<boolean>(() => false);
```

2. Pass the context in your login request

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpContext } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

login() {
  this.httpClient.post(
    'https://example.com/login',
    data,
    {
      context: new HttpContext().set(DISABLE_AUTH_HEADER, true);
    }
  ).subscribe(...);
}
```

3. Read the context in your interceptor

```js
intercept(
  httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>,
  next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  if(httpRequest.context.get(DISABLE_AUTH_HEADER) === true)
    return next.handle(httpRequest); // Continue to the next handler

  //...
}
```